# Compiler cannot locate header file in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When attempting to compile a C++ program in VS Code I'm getting an error. The Executing task is: cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /Fe: 'c:\Users\Me\Documents\cpp\VRP\program.exe' 'c:\Users\Me\Documents\cpp\VRP\program.cc'

The error I get is:
program.cc
c:\Users\Me\Documents\cpp\VRP\program.cc(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'linear_solver/linear_solver.h': No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1.

The first line in my program.cc file is: `#include "linear_solver/linear_solver.h"`

The Path "C:\Users\Me\Documents\CPP\or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v7.6.7691" is in my Environment Variables. The full path to where the header file "linear_solver.h" is located is "C:\Users\Me\Documents\cpp\or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v7.6.7691\include\ortools\linear_solver\". How do I direct the Microsoft C++ (MSVC) "cl.exe" compiler to locate that directory/file or modify the include statement to work in Visual Studio Code?

My c_cpp_properties.json file is:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/Me/Documents/cpp/or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v7.6.7691/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",            
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My launch.json is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "cl.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

My tasks.json is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
          "/Zi",
          "/EHsc",
          "/Fe:",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to add the include path in your `tasks.json` the `c_cpp_properties.json` file is for intellisense not for the compiler.

Comment: Does `c:\Users\Me\Documents\cpp\VRP` have a `linear_solver` folder?

Comment: @drescherjm No, it does not. That folder is in the path C:\Users\me\Documents\cpp\or-tools_VisualStudio2019-64bit_v7.6.7691\include\ortools\linear_solver